# Settings application required

Tags: iphone, preferences

My app use a Settings bundle to manage preferences from the Settings application.

How can I make mandatory the inclusion of these preferences? If the user starts the application without having set its preferences I can tell to the user that before using the application should set preferences?

Many thanks!

Comment: that doesn't seem very practical for the user... why can't you start with some default settings?

Comment: because the application requires the user to enter a phone number preferred. the application is based on that phone number

Answer (score 0):

The more user-friendly way to do this would be to have a setup screen that asks for the required information if it has not been entered yet.

To detect if anything has been set, just check the return from [NSUserDefaults objectForKey:]. If it is nil, then you know that nothing has been entered yet.